# Install QGIS plugin manually - Package not available in Plugin Manager

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

If it is helpful, I am using QGIS 3.4.3 (Madeira) and MacOS High Sierra v10.13.6

I am trying to install a QGIS plugin manually, I've been using the instructions from the PyQGIS Programmer's Guide by Gary Sherman. I've also found several helpful threads on stackoverflow such as:

[How to install a QGIS plugin when offline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline)

[installing plugins manually](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245007/installing-plugins-manually?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to Install QGIS 2.6 plugins offline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127785/how-to-install-qgis-2-6-plugins-offline?rq=1) (Though I am using version 3.4)

I've created a plugin on a local drive using the Plugin Builder.

I have compiled the resources file using the following (in the terminal) which is straight from the QGIS documentation

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

and I copied my plugin directory to my QGIS plugins directory.  Here is a screenshot of my directory, with some other plugins I've installed using the Plugin Manager. My test plugin is called "whereisthis":
[image]

When I open the Plugin Manager in QGIS, the other plugins in the same folder are visible under installed (such as NNJoin, mmqgis, EcoValuator) but 'whereisthis' is not on the list:
[image]

The book states: "You should now see your plugin in the list of installed plugins". But it is not there.

According to the other stackoverflow threads which I referenced earlier, I have reloaded my repository, I have enabled experimental plugins, I have rebooted QGIS and my machine (several times).

I also edited my metadata.txt file to make sure the correct minimum and maximum versions are available:
[image]

The plugin is also not in the "Invalid" tab of the Plugin Manager:

[image]

Is there something else I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you check the "Invalid" page, 4th from the top on the left of your Plugin Manager screenshot and change your file-system screenshot to expand the 'whereareyou' folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, your problem is in this command:

```
pyrcc5 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

QGIS documentation has some issues due lack of adequate actualization. I did same plugin and right command is:

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Additional details can be observed here:

[Compiling resources in QGIS 2.99 (Windows) for creating plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263243/compiling-resources-in-qgis-2-99-windows-for-creating-plugin)

where same plugin works perfectly.

Comment: I was able to create the new resources.py file and I also edited my metadata.txt file (according to Gary Johnson who replied to your thread). And now my plugin is available.  Thank you very much!

Comment: It was the own founder of QGIS, Gary Sherman, not Gary Johnson.